# AngularJS $HTTP error status of -1

Tags: angularjs

I currently have an error intercept set up in AngularJS to catch any failed HTTP requests so that I can notify myself when it occurs. Occasionally (but often enough) I get an error with a status of -1. I have no idea what this means or why its occurring... Anyone have any explanations?

```
appService.factory("$errorInterceptor", ['$q', '$injector', function ($q,$injector) {
    var errorInterceptor = {
        responseError: function (response) {
            var $http = $injector.get('$http');

            if (response.status !== 401 && response.status !== 409) {
                var error = {
                    status: response.status,
                    message: JSON.stringify(response),
                    url: window.location.href,
                };

                $http.post("/api/errors/angular", error);
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    }

    return errorInterceptor;
}])
```

and the repsponse I'm getting is..

```
 {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"PUT","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"/api/baskets/changedeliverymethod/10","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

EDIT:
I have never actually been able to produce this myself. Just get it randomly from all types of devices/browsers.

Comment: That should just be the HTTP response code, maybe the server is doing an odd response code? What does the request look like in your network traffic?

Comment: that -1 is a special status in angular, added half a year ago, as far as i remember, may be related to promise manipulation.

Comment: Have you looked in your console for errors? I generally see that with a CORS related issue.

Comment: @YOU thanks for the comment. So I dug around angular source code and it appears they're setting this status when a request has a timeout parameter or gets aborted... Not setting the timeout so presumably this request is somehow getting aborted maybe?